# ¿Como actualizar el saldo de JFrame en java sin base de datos?

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

No me actualiza nada en la tabla ni en la variable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto esta dentro del botón operar

```
// TODO add your handling code here:
int ingreso = Integer.parseInt(txtIngreso.getText());
int saldo=0;

if(cmbOpe.getSelectedIndex()==0){
    saldo = ingreso + saldo;
    modelo.addRow(new Object[]{cmbOpe.getSelectedItem(), String.valueOf(ingreso),String.valueOf(saldo)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el `ingreso` es 10, y el `saldo` es 0, la declaración `saldo=ingreso+saldo` siempre será 10. La variable de **saldo** debe obtener el ultimo registro de la columna **"Saldo actual"** en la tabla, de modo que recupere el ultimo valor y le puedas sumar el nuevo ingreso.

El código se puede mejorar, pero en principio la solución es la siguiente.

```
int ingreso = Integer.parseInt(txtIngreso.getText());
int saldo = 0;

if (model.getRowCount() != 0) {
    Integer ultimoSaldo = (Integer) model.getValueAt(model.getRowCount() - 1, model.findColumn("Saldo actual"));
    saldo = ultimoSaldo;
}

if (cmbOpe.getSelectedIndex() == 0) { // DEPOSITAR
    saldo = ingreso + saldo;
}

model.addRow(new Object[] { cmbOpe.getSelectedItem(), ingreso, saldo });
```

Esto hace que si el ultimo saldo era 10, y el ingreso es 15, la declaración sea 10+15 y no 10+0.

Puedes remplazar código de "findColumn" por el indice de la columna, al utilizar el mismo modelo aunque muevas las columnas de lugar Swing sabe en que columna querías que esté ese valor.